# avoiding IN in the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables

M, R, G, D, PT and PI

PI has relationship with all the other tables.
There is a parent - child relationship of M, R, G and D.

Example : model id will be there in M and R
          Range id will be there in R and G
          Grade id will be there in G and D

To know a derivative which is published, an example is as below

```
 SELECT D.DERIVATIVE_ID
 FROM   PRD.DERIVATIVE D
        JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM PI ON PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_ID = D.DERIVATIVE_ID
                                      AND PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_TYPE = 'DERIVATIVE'
        JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET PT ON PI.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID = PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID
 WHERE  D.DERIVATIVE_ID = 683239
```

To know a Model which is published, an example is as below

```
SELECT  *
FROM    PRD.MODEL M
        JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM PI ON PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_ID = M.MODEL_ID
                                      AND PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_TYPE = 'MODEL'
        JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET PT ON PI.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID = PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID
WHERE   M.model_id = 257
```

**I would like to write a query to display Models, whose derivatives are published but not the models (models are not published)**

Here is what I tried, your feedback would be helpful

```
SELECT  *
FROM    PRD.MODEL M
        JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM PI ON PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_ID = M.MODEL_ID
                                      AND PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_TYPE = 'MODEL'
        JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET PT ON PI.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID <> PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID
        JOIN PRD.RANGE R ON R.MODEL_ID = M.MODEL_ID
        JOIN PRD.GRADE G ON G.RANGE_ID = R.RANGE_ID
        JOIN prd.DERIVATIVE D ON D.GRADE_ID = G.GRADE_ID
                                 AND D.DERIVATIVE_ID IN (
                                 SELECT D.DERIVATIVE_ID
                                 FROM   PRD.DERIVATIVE D
                                        JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM PI ON PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_ID = D.DERIVATIVE_ID
                                                              AND PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_TYPE = 'DERIVATIVE'
                                        JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET PT ON PI.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID = PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID )
```

Also in the above query, **how can I avoid using "IN" ?**

Comment: thx for reformatting, what tool do you use?

Comment: I use SQL Prompt - well worth the cost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual method is `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM PRD.MODEL M
JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM PI
    ON PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_ID = M.MODEL_ID
        AND PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_TYPE = 'MODEL'
JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET PT
    ON PI.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID <> PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID
JOIN PRD.RANGE R
    ON R.MODEL_ID = M.MODEL_ID
JOIN PRD.GRADE G
    ON G.RANGE_ID = R.RANGE_ID
JOIN prd.DERIVATIVE D
    ON D.GRADE_ID = G.GRADE_ID
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM PRD.DERIVATIVE D_s
        JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM PI_s
            ON  PI_s.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_ID = D_S.DERIVATIVE_ID
            AND PI_s.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_TYPE = 'DERIVATIVE'
        JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET PT_s
            ON PI_s.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID = PT_s.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID
        WHERE D_s.DERIVATIVE_ID =  D.DERIVATIVE_ID
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `INNER Join` you can avoid.

```
SELECT *
FROM   PRD.MODEL M
       JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM PI
         ON PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_ID = M.MODEL_ID
            AND PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_TYPE = 'MODEL'
       JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET PT
         ON PI.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID <> PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID
       JOIN PRD.RANGE R
         ON R.MODEL_ID = M.MODEL_ID
       JOIN PRD.GRADE G
         ON G.RANGE_ID = R.RANGE_ID
       JOIN prd.DERIVATIVE d
         ON d.GRADE_ID = g.GRADE_ID
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT D.DERIVATIVE_ID
             FROM   PRD.DERIVATIVE D
                    JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM PI
                      ON PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_ID = D.DERIVATIVE_ID
                         AND PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_TYPE = 'DERIVATIVE'
                    JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET PT
                      ON PI.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID = PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID) AA
         ON D.DERIVATIVE_ID = AA.DERIVATIVE_ID
```

By using `Exists`

```
SELECT *
FROM   PRD.MODEL M
       JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM PI
         ON PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_ID = M.MODEL_ID
            AND PI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_TYPE = 'MODEL'
       JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET PT
         ON PI.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID <> PT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID
       JOIN PRD.RANGE R
         ON R.MODEL_ID = M.MODEL_ID
       JOIN PRD.GRADE G
         ON G.RANGE_ID = R.RANGE_ID
       JOIN prd.DERIVATIVE D
         ON D.GRADE_ID = G.GRADE_ID
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
               FROM   PRD.DERIVATIVE ED
                      JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_ITEM EPI
                        ON EPI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_ID = ED.DERIVATIVE_ID
                           AND EPI.PUBLISHED_OBJECT_TYPE = 'DERIVATIVE'
                      JOIN PUB.PUBLISHED_TARGET EPT
                        ON EPI.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID = EPT.PUBLISHED_TARGET_ID
               WHERE  ED.DERIVATIVE_ID = D.DERIVATIVE_ID)
```

Comment: Thanks For the response, they are helpful